# Why would two console applications on the same machine return different results from Directory.Exists(sameDirectory)?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have two .net console applications, and I F10 to debug and stop on the first line of both apps on the same machine.

Then I add the following watch to both Visual Studios: `Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\MyDirectory")`

What could be the possible reasons why the one application would return `true` while the other returns `false`.

The application that returns `true` is wrong, and I can verify it in Windows Explorer and create and delete the directory.

I tried the following on the application that mistakenly returns `true`:

1. Excluded the *app.manifest* file, rebuilt and debug again.
2. Removed the following from the *app.config* file:

---

```
<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

3. Neither of the Visual Studios are running as administrator, in Task Manager and through `System.Environment.UserName` I am pretty sure both are running as the same user.

What else could cause this behavior?

Comment: do you `Console.WriteLine` the results or do you inspect the values with an mouse-(h)over?

Comment: @cramopy, I F10 once and then while the debugger is paused on the first line I add the watch to both Visual Studios.

Comment: are both console applications run from the same directory ? Maybe one is run from a subfolder in "my programs" and the other is not ?

Comment: if you're using vs17rc you can encounter the very rare problem as described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3960/live-debugging-tuples-does-show-wrong-values.html). due to the fact that you're giving in the full path I don't know any other reason (which could fit for your problem) at the moment.

Comment: @GuidoG, `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` confirms that the one app is running from "C:\Users\xxxx\documents\Visual Studio Projects\console1" and the other running from "C:\Service\TheProject". So in both cases "C:\Program Files\MyDirectory" should work fine.

Comment: It could be as simple as different strings, e.g. extra space.

Comment: @Sinatr, I know, thanks, I copied and pasted the watched value. There is no difference. Same problem. I'm now re assembling the larger console app that isn't working, from scratch, to see if a process of elimination would reveal anything.

Comment: @MartinLottering, is there a corresponding folder present under `%localappdata%\VirtualStore`? I know you've said you've stripped pared everything back and checked that they two console applications are running as the same identity, but that's the only thing I can think of here (`%localappdata%` maps to `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local`)

Comment: @Rob, yes, the directory exists there. Thanks for the info. So it seems the one app reads the VirtualStore while the other doesn't. I restarted the one Visual Studio and now both show the same `false` at the first line. But the directories still exist in VirtualStore.

Comment: @MartinLottering, isn't technology great! ;-) VirtualStore has caught me out once or twice before, it's odd that two instances of Visual Studio were being inconsistent about whether they saw it or not though. Was one running as Administrator, perhaps? It might be worth looking at the *creation* date of the folder in VirtualStore and seeing if that gives you any hints as to why the two were behaving inconsistently, e.g. after looking at the creation date you think that one of the VS instances would have been opened *before* and the other *after* =)

Comment: @Rob, thanks again. I will now investigate using this new information about the VirtualStore. You have been a tremendous help! Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it for you.

Comment: @MartinLottering, done - glad I could help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by the [File and Registry Virtualisation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richard_macdonald/2007/05/18/windows-vista-file-and-registry-virtualisation/) that was first introduced in Windows Vista, this means that when an application meets the criteria it will see reads/writes to protected locations redirected to folders under the path `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore` (which can also be reached as `%localappdata%\VirtualStore`. This means that two different applications can get a different view of the contents of the `Program Files` folder, for example:

> C:\Users[Your_User_Name]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\common7\ide

to take an example folder that I have which exists in my `VirtualStore` folder hierarchy.